# Formatting JSON data for DynamoDB using jq

Tags: json, amazon-dynamodb, jq

Trying to format a json object into a proper format for DynamoDB in shell

```
{ "200": 1728, "201": 288, "301": 214, "401": 104, "404": 12 }
```

I originally had a script that I figured was the proper format, but the data retrieved is dynamic as it can have any number of keys

```
jq -r '.codes' item.json | jq --slurp '{Codes:{M: .[]}}'
```

outputs

```
{"Codes": {"M": { "200": 1728, "201": 288, "301": 214, "401": 104, "404": 12 }}}
```

DynamoDB format, the one field that will be static is "N", but the numbers have to be formatted to string, which I may be able to do in the initial filter

```
{"Codes": {"M": { "200": {"N": "1728"}, "201": {"N": "288"}, "301": {"N": "214"}, "401": {"N": 104}, "404": {"N": "12"} }}}
```

It took me 4 days to try getting what Ive gotten so far, and am stuck as to formatting it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the problem, the piece of the puzzle you're missing is the ability to transform a JSON object {key1: value1, key2: value2, ...} into an object of the form: {key1: {"N": (value1|tostring)}, ...

This can be done using the filter:

```
to_entries | map( {(.key): {N: (.value|tostring)}} ) | add;
```

It might be worthwhile wrapping this functionality into a named function:

```
def package: to_entries | map( {(.key): {N: (.value|tostring)}} ) | add;
```

The solution to the problem (as I understand it) can then be written:

```
{Codes: {M: package}}
```

Input:

```
{ "200": 1728, "201": 288, "301": 214, "401": 104, "404": 12 }
```

Output:

```
{
  "Codes": {
    "M": {
      "200": {
        "N": "1728"
      },
      "201": {
        "N": "288"
      },
      "301": {
        "N": "214"
      },
      "401": {
        "N": "104"
      },
      "404": {
        "N": "12"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: wow, one filter solved my other two problems too. :D thank you for your thorough response. This is definitely a timesaver